# React authorizing user access

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

beginner here. I have the following code which gives access to various pages depending on the presence of a user and him being an admin.

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined);
const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);
   useEffect(() => {
     const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
     if (user) {
        setCurrentUser(user);
        if (user.isAdmin)
           setIsAdmin(true);
     }
  }, []);
```

```
  <Route exact path={"/"} element={<Home props={currentUser} />} />

  <Route exact path="/login" element={!currentUser ? <Login /> : <Navigate to='/' />} />
  
  <Route exact path="/watch/:id" element={isAdmin ? <Watch /> : <Navigate to='/login' />} />

  <Route exact path="/movies" element={<Movies />} />

  <Route exact path="/admin"  >
    <Route index element={isAdmin ? <AdminPage /> : <Navigate to='/' />} />    
    <Route path="moviespanel">
      <Route index element={<Moviespanel />} />              
  </Route>
```

Now, the conditions in 4 first routes work just fine. the one in index element does not work when isAdmin variable changes from false to true. It does not work in any different way i write it.
isAdmin === true ? ... : ... etc etc

Bear in mind that the same condition is in Route /watch and there it works perfectly fine. Does it matter that it is in an index element ?

I tried to use isAdmin &&  which works for both conditions but i do not know how to get it to Navigate to "/" when isAdmin is false.

...
Edit,

I actually found out that the condition works if I follow the paths through buttons/links, they do not work when I type in the url directly in the browser.

Is there something in the ternary operator "?" that i do not know ?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this works perhaps? I haven't really used react-router-dom specifically, but still.

```
  <Route exact path="/admin">
    { isAdmin ? (
      <Fragment>
        <Route index element={<AdminPage />} />
        <Route path="/movies" element={<AdminMovies />} />

        {/* more <Route path= ... here? */}
      </Fragment>
    ) : (
      <Navigate to='/' />
    )}   
  </Route>
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. the problem is that on that Route only, when isAdmin changes, it gets a value that I can not match with anything. It is not false, true, null, undefined etc...

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Typically you'd abstract the authentication and/or roles status into a wrapper component to be used on specific routes. This issue is ***almost always*** that the initial state values for users and roles match the unauthenticated or disallowed role values. In other words, the initial state matches what you protect/guard and keep users from accessing.

## Solutions

The solution is to either use a loading state or indeterminate initial state values to force the UI to wait until an authentication/role status is ***confirmed***.

### Using a loading state

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined);
const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
  if (user) {
    setCurrentUser(user);
    setIsAdmin(user.isAdmin);
  }
  setIsLoading(false);
}, []);

...

if (isLoading) {
  return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc...
}

return (
  ...
  <Route path={"/"} element={<Home props={currentUser} />} />
  <Route path="/login" element={!currentUser ? <Login /> : <Navigate to='/' />} />
  <Route path="/watch/:id" element={isAdmin ? <Watch /> : <Navigate to='/login' />} />
  <Route path="/movies" element={<Movies />} />
  <Route path="/admin">
    <Route index element={isAdmin ? <AdminPage /> : <Navigate to='/' />} />    
    <Route path="moviespanel">
      <Route index element={<Moviespanel />} />              
    </Route>
  </Route>
  ...
);
```

### Using indeterminate initial state values

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(); // <-- undefined
const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState();         // <-- undefined

useEffect(() => {
  const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
  if (user) {
    setCurrentUser(user);     // <-- defined
    setIsAdmin(user.isAdmin); // <-- defined
  }
}, []);

...

return (
  ...
  <Route path={"/"} element={<Home props={currentUser} />} />
  <Route
    path="/login"
    element={currentUser === undefined
      ? null
      : currentUser
        ? <Navigate to='/' />
        : <Login />
    }
  />
  <Route
    path="/watch/:id"
    element={isAdmin === undefined
      ? null
      : isAdmin
        ? <Watch />
        : <Navigate to='/login' />
    }
  />
  <Route path="/movies" element={<Movies />} />
  <Route path="/admin">
    <Route
      index
      element={isAdmin === undefined
        ? null
        : isAdmin
          ? <AdminPage />
          : <Navigate to='/' />
      }
    />    
    <Route path="moviespanel">
      <Route index element={<Moviespanel />} />              
    </Route>
  </Route>
  ...
);
```

### Wrapper components

For either solution, using a wrapper component allows for cleaner, more DRY code. Ideally you'd also move the state into a React context or similar and access directly in the wrapper components instead of passing in as props. This is just to provide an idea for code structure/organization.

Example:

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ isLoading, user }) => {
  if (isLoading) return null;
  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/login' replace />;
};

const AdminRoute = ({ isLoading, isAdmin }) => {
  if (isLoading) return null;
  return isAdmin ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/' replace />;
};

const AnonymousRoute = ({ isLoading, user }) => {
  if (isLoading) return null;
  return user ? <Navigate to='/' replace /> : <Outlet />;
};
```

...

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(undefined);
const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState(false);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
  if (user) {
    setCurrentUser(user);
    setIsAdmin(user.isAdmin);
  }
  setIsLoading(false);
}, []);

...

return (
  ... public routes ...
  <Route path="/" element={<Home props={currentUser} />} />
  <Route path="/movies" element={<Movies />} />

  <Route element={<AnonymousRoute isLoading={isLoading} user={currentUser} />}>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  </Route>

  <Route element={<PrivateRoute isLoading={isLoading} user={currentUser} />}>
    ... authenticated routes ...

    <Route element={<AdminRoute isLoading={isLoading} isAdmin={isAdmin}/>}>
      ... admin routes ...
      <Route path="/watch/:id" element={<Watch />} />
      <Route path="/admin">
        <Route index element={<AdminPage />} />    
        <Route path="moviespanel" element={<Moviespanel />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
  ...
);
```